# project2 has reference of project1. we are receiving a event in project1 and on receiving the event, need to update gridview available in project2

Tags: android, events

I have 2 projects project1 and project2. Project2 has reference to project1. We are receiving an event in project1 and we need to update `GridView` in project2. I have tried custom event handler. How we can handle this situation? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Signals from my [LifeCycle](https://github.com/gazman-sdk/Life-Cycle/wiki) library for that.

```
interface LogSignal{
    void onLog(String message);
}

Class A implements LogSignal{
    void onLog(String message){
          System.out.println(message);
    }
}

Class B{
     LogSignal logSignal = SignalsBag.inject(LogSignal.class).dispatcher;

     void run(){
          logSignal.onLog("Run is started");
     }
}

Class Main{
     public static void main(String args[]){
           SignalsBag.inject(LogSignal.class).addListener(A.class);
           new B().run();
     }
}
```

Output:

> Run is started